# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module './V2/Admin/Events/Partials/EventIntegrationGuide'

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am working on a Laravel, Vue3, and inertiajs project

This the controller function:

```php
public function embedEvent(Request $request, Event $event)
{
    return Inertia::render('V2/Admin/Events/Partials/EventIntegrationGuide', [
        'event' => new EventResource($event),
    ]);
}
```

And this is the router:

```php
Route::get('/event/embed/{event}', [EventController::class, 'embedEvent'])->name('events.embed');
```

This is the path of the component:

[image: /resources/js/Pages/V2/Admin/Events/Partials/EventIntegrationGuide.vue]

I tried these commands:

```bash
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache

php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

When I pushed my updates to my teammate its working fine for him.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code textual information such as the paths of files **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: this can be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990206/laravel-8-inertia-js-getting-vue-error-app-js30559-vue-warn-error-in-cr

Comment: No this not related